# Hahn-Banach extension of $g.$

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with $\|.\|_{1}$ norm and $M=\{(x,0):x\in\mathbb{R}\}.$ Define $g:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $g(x,y)=x.$ Then Hahn-Banach extension $f$ of $g$ is given by

$A.f(x,y)=2x.$

$B.f(x,y)=x+y.$

$C.f(x,y)=x+2y.$

$D.f(x,y)=x-2y.$

I tried it as follows

$g(x,y)=x=<(x,y),(1,0)>\implies \|g\|=1,$ but in any case we have $\|f\|\neq1$ so i have no correct option. Please suggest me .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choice B is the only one that will fit the requirements of the Hahn-Banach theorem; it indeed satisfies $\|f\| = 1$.  For options C-D, there exists an $(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y) > \|(x,y)\|_1$, contrary to the required property.

Comment: How $\|f\|$=1??$

Comment: We have $\|f\| \leq 1$ since $|f(x,y)| = |x+y| \leq |x| + |y| = \|(x,y)\|_1$

Comment: But $f(x,y)=x+y=<(x,y),(1,1)>\implies \|f\|=\|(1,1)\|$ by Riesz representation theorem?

Comment: That's only true in the Hilbert space $(\Bbb R^2, \|\cdot\|_2)$.  We have a different norm here.

Comment: Where is my mistake in last comment?? please suggest me..

Comment: @neelkanth I already "suggested you" where the mistake in your last comment is.  The Riesz representation theorem applies only to Hilbert spaces.  Our functions $f$ and $g$ are **not** functions on a Hilbert space.

Comment: But finite dimensional inner product spaces spaces are Hilbert???

Comment: No, finite dimensional normed linear spaces are not Hilber.  A Hilbert space must have an inner product.  In order for a norm to come from an inner product, it must satisfy the parallelogram law (and the inner product could then be recovered by the polarization identity).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44037/discussion-between-neelkanth-and-omnomnomnom).

Comment: See, usually the comment "let us continue this discussion in chat" indicates a desired to continue the discussion in chat...