# Hahn-Banach extension of function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\|\;.\,\|_1$-norm

Tags: banach-spaces

Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ with  $\|\;.\,\|_1$-norm and $M=\{(x,0) \mid x \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Define $g:M \to \mathbb{R}$ by $g(x,y)=x$. Then a Hahn-Banach extension $f$ of $g$ is given by

a) $f(x,y)=2x$

b) $f(x,y)=x+y $

c) $f(x,y)=x-2y $

d) $f(x,y)=x+2y$

Comment: This question looks incoherent as written.  Probably there are some typos where "$f(x+y)$" should instead read "$f(x,y)$". In this case, the most obvious HB extension $f$ of $g$ is given by the rule $f(x,y)=x+y$. The other functionals all have norm 2, and thus are not HB extensions.

Comment: yes...thanks for correction

Comment: Possible duplicate of "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1893823/hahn-banach-extension-of-g"

Answer (score 0):

The subspace is spanned by only one vector viz. $(1,0)$, so any linear functional on $M$ is just a real scalar. Although any linear functional on $M$ has uncountably many HB extensions.

Answer (score 0):

See Ben Wallis's comment above:

> The most obvious HB extension $f$ of $g$ is given by the rule $f(x,y)=x+y$. The other functionals all have norm $2$, and thus are not HB extensions.

Comment: @BenWallis feel free to add your own answer with more detail

Comment: thanx..plz  explain it thorouhly..

Comment: Then tell me what part you don't understand. What's confusing you here?

Comment: I can not understand f(x,y)=x+y? what is actual reason